# Disk usage in stat output and inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-usage

Below is my stat output:

```
[alankoh@SJOAM swap]$ stat myswapfile 
  File: `myswapfile'
  Size: 2147483648  Blocks: 4194312    IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 1179650     Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-08-06 16:22:28.672852866 +0800
Modify: 2015-07-02 07:39:04.781064916 +0800
Change: 2015-07-02 07:39:04.809064917 +0800
```

Does the blocks allocated (4194312) include the size of the inode itself or it refers to the "actual data" portion?

How do we find a size of the above inode then?

> the size of the physical block is 512 x 4194312 blocks allocated =
>   2147487744 bytes
>
> the size of of the file is 2147483648 bytes
>
> 2147487744 - 2147483648 = 4096 bytes
>
> 4096 bytes = IO Block

How is the above related calculation related to the IO Block ? is IO Block the per allocation unit each time a file need space ? 4096 = 8 blocks x 512 bytes ?

Answer (score 4):

What the “Blocks” value (the `st_blocks` field of a [`struct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html)) measures exactly is not standardized.

Traditionally, it counts the number of blocks that are used for filesystem content; this value multiplied by the block size is equal to the file size, rounded up to the nearest multiple of the block size. There's an exception: if the file is a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), then it uses fewer blocks. This leaves several things unaccounted:

- Space consumed by the file's metadata: timestamps, permissions, etc. In the traditional Unix layout, this is stored in an inode, but modern filesystems can have large metadata (for access control lists, extended security attributes, etc.) which doesn't always fit in a fixed-size inode.
- Space consumed by indirect blocks: for large files, the list of blocks that contain file contents can itself use up many blocks.
- Space consumed by the directory entry (or entries, if the file has multiple hard links). This space is accounted for in the size of the directory itself.

I don't know of a filesystem that reports the inode size as part of the `st_blocks` value. Most Unix filesystems have a layout that separates inodes from the rest of the content, and track inode usage and block usage separately. Some filesystems include indirect blocks in `st_blocks`, others don't.

There are other things that can cause differences between the block size and the content size. For example, on a compressed filesystem, the relationship depends on how much the file can be compressed. Some filesystems can share a block between several small files or tails of larger files, e.g. a 1024-byte block could contain both a 200-byte file and the last 100 bytes of a 1124-byte file, and that block would be counted in the `st_blocks` value for both files.

The “IO Block” value (`st_blksize` field of `struct stat`) is not related to the “Blocks” value in any way. The `st_blksize` value is a hint to applications that they'll get better performance if they use a buffer of this size when reading or writing to the file. On a modern system with complex performance characteristics, it may or may not have any relevance.

On many systems, the unit for the `st_blocks` value is the `f_bsize` value from [`struct statvfs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html). This unit can vary between filesystems (even filesystems of the same type, e.g. ext4 can use 1024, 2048 or 4096). I think that's always the case on Linux, but it isn't guaranteed by POSIX. On Linux, you can display the `f_bsize` value with `stat -f`.

The `du` utility will make the correct calculation when it calculates the disk usage for a file: what `du` does is to multiply the `st_blocks` value by the appropriate block size (so it won't include the inode on most systems).

There's no generic way to find the size of an inode. Some filesystem types use fixed-sized inodes, which you can look up in the definition of the filesystem. Some filesystem types use a fixed size for a given filesystem, which you can query with a utility (e.g. `tune2fs` for ext[234]).

Answer (score 0):

Use tune2fs to determine inode size of the filesystem.

```
$ df -k /
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        9156984 7509468   1159324  87% /
$ tune2fs -l /dev/sda1|grep "^Inode size:"
Inode size:               256
$
```

Comment: steve, does that means that the "Used" portion is the actual data being used and does not include the size of the inode  ? right ?